# Help with proving that all ζ ∈ ℚ have a periodic decimal expansion

Tags: real-numbers

I've been trying to prove that all ζ ∈ ℚ have periodic decimal expansion. I assume that a terminating decimal expansion counts as a periodic decimal expansion as well since the zeros are periodic as well.

I managed to prove that for all ζ ∈ ℝ with a periodic decimal expansion we have that ζ ∈ ℚ. However, I don't know how to prove that all ζ ∈ ℚ have a periodic decimal expansion. Any tips on how I can prove this?

I've seen answers to my question involving terms like "mod" and "ring" but am not familiar with these terms so my question still stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decimal expansion of a rational number is the result of the operation of long division. Look at the long division algorithm for a specific rational number that results in a repeating decimal. Notice that three are only so many remainders that come up. Once you see the same one again, you're in repetition.

Can you get a proof out of that observation?

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks for the comment.